# UIApplicationMain class function inside ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, appdelegate, uiapplication

I have a functionality throughout my application. Now i need to call a specific function inside one view controller for some particular condition. So i tried to call, but it fails

main.swift

```
CommandLine.unsafeArgv.withMemoryRebound(to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.self, capacity: Int(CommandLine.argc))
{   argv in
    _ = UIApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, argv, NSStringFromClass(MyClass.self), NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self))
}
```

MyClass.swift

```
class MyClass: UIApplication {
  func resetIdleTimer() {

  }
}
```

MyViewController.swift

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    MyClass.resetIdleTimer(); //this causes error in 
}
```

I need to call `resetIdleTimer()` inside `MyViewController`?

Comment: Your function is instance type and you are calling it as like class function.

Comment: i was about to use it as `static func  resetIdleTimer()` but that made to change so many place and affects `main.swift`. So another solution?

Comment: you can check my answer, I have checked and it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code, You can call it from anywhere.

```
if let obj = MyClass.shared as? MyClass {
    obj.resetIdleTimer()
}
```

For ex. You can call in view controller

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      if let obj = MyClass.shared as? MyClass {
          obj.resetIdleTimer()
      }
    }
}
```